# Как правильно организовать динамический поиск VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

в App.vue

у меня есть watch, который отслеживает this.$route.query

```
watch: {
  '$route.query': {
    handler: function(query_string) {
      // здесь код
    },
    deep: true,
    immediate: true
  } 
}
```

и есть метод router_push, который добавляет (или заменяет значение) GET-параметры к пути.

```
router_push(query_string) {
    let query_object = Object.fromEntries(query_string.split("&").map((pair) => pair.split("=")))
    for (let key in router.currentRoute.query) {
      for (let key_inner in query_object) {
        if (key_inner !== key) {
          query_object[key] = router.currentRoute.query[key]
        }
      }
    }
    const result_query_string = Object.entries(query_object)
      .map((pair) => pair.join("="))
      .join("&");
    router.push(`${router.currentRoute.path}?${result_query_string}`).catch(err => console.log(err))

  },
```

Исходя из логики, все должно работать, однако происходит ошибка
Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/?search_type=device_title&search=1"

Как-то нужно всё через params оформить, но у меня тут я не знаю сколько GET-параметров будет

Answer (score 2):

Сообщение *"Avoided redundant navigation to current location"* означает то, что vue-router предотвратил переход по текущему (тому же самому) пути.

Наилучшим способом обхода такой ситуации, является проверка на отличие нового пути от текущего, перед вызовом метода `router.push`: если новый путь то же самый, то метод не вызывать.
Проверку можно выполнить используя массив `$route.matched` - [об этом написано в официальной документации](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/meta.html), плюс еще пример кода проверки можно найти [в ответе @AdonisGaitatzis на enSO (решение №2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64485378/12506088).

---

Другим, плохим решением - будет подавление ошибок бросаемых методом `push`. В твоем коде, для этого достаточно будет убрать вызов `console.log(err)`... но делать так я не советую.
Меньшим злом (но все же злом) будет такой вариант, который подавляет только часть ошибок:

```
router.push(route).catch(err => {
  // Игнорируем ошибки относящиеся к переходу на ту же самую страницу
  if (
    err.name !== 'NavigationDuplicated' &&
    !err.message.includes('Avoided redundant navigation to current location')
  ) {
    // но выводим/обрабатываем все прочие ошибки
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

<sup>[Источник - ответ @Luckylooke на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63258706/12506088)</sup>